# New Flutter project only has .idea folder and .iml file

Tags: flutter, android-studio

this is my first time actually posting a question on here, despite already having frequently browsed this wonderful platform for answers before, so apologies if there is something missing or if it isn't too clear.
I'm somewhat new to flutter and android studio, and am currently wondering why when creating a new flutter project on android studio, only the .idea folder and .iml file appear under the main folder [https://i.imgur.com/6YMkkv3.png]
I've also run flutter doctor and while it did show 2 issues, I'm almost positive they were already present before and did not pose a problem [https://i.imgur.com/1IshqrQ.pngl]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the following guide [Set up an editor](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/editor?tab=androidstudio) to set up your editor to work with Flutter, and then [Test drive](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=androidstudio) to create a Flutter project.

`.idea` is a folder that is created by Intellij IDEA and contains metadata about your workspace like settings, run configs etc..

`.iml` contains module metadata.

For the chrome issue, try running
`flutter config --enable-web`

Comment: I thought I'd retraced my steps and checked I was creating the project correctly, but it looks like I really wasn't after all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also searching for this question. But solved this issue. This is happened because of flutter SDK path in android studio.
If you didn't download flutter SDK Click here [Download Flutter SDK](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows)

First click on "New Flutter project"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDVnY.png)

> On left side you will see flutter click on flutter
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrYDF.jpg)

Click on three dots and give location of flutter SDK folder.
then give name of you flutter project and it will take some time to create flutter project.